# How to call method from parent container

Tags: php, design-patterns, containers

I have container which contains other containers, which can contains other containers and so on. Object `container1` have special methods `foo()` and I want to call this method from `container3`. How can I do this?

I thought about *Singleton* design pattern, but in my program exists more than one object of class `MyClass1`. I thought about *Delegate* design pattern, but `container2` don't has to know nothing about `MyClass1` (there is no need to this).

```
container1:MyClass1
|
+--container2:MyClass2
|  |
|  +---container3:MyClass3
|  |
|  +---container3:MyClass3
|
+---container4:MyClass4
```

Comment: but how you know the structure? why cant you just in container3 go by parent ids to get your parent item, and call that function for that object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some way of Dependency Injection pattern.

A little example:

```
interface FooContainer 
{
   function foo();
}

Class Injector
{
    private diContainer;

    static function getInstance() 
    {
       <singleton>
    }

    function addDependency(FooContainer $class, $key)  
    {
       $this->diContainer[$key] = $class;
    }

    function getDependency($key) 
    {
       return $this->diContainer[$key];
    }
}

Class Container1 implements FooContainer
{
    function foo()
    {
        echo "Foo"
    }
}

Class Container3
{
    private fooClass;

    function setFoo()
    {
        $this->fooClass = Injector::getInstance()->getDependency("foo");
        return $this;
    }

    function foo()
    {
        $this->fooClass->foo();
    }
}
```

and you call it like this.

```
$container1 = new Container1();
/** do whatever you need */
Injector::getInstance()->addDependency($container1, "foo");    
$container3 = new Container3();    
$container3->setFoo()->foo();
```

Comment: This is not the same as Delegate pattern? And how would you solve the issue that adding `container3` to `container2`, `container2` doesn't know anything about `container1`. So how can set `fooClass`?

Comment: Does container3 know about container2?

Comment: No. Each container has its own work to do and not interested in the other containers. Only `container3` must be able to inform `container1` the results of its work.

Comment: Remade the code using actual DI container. It is the simplest form of injection, but still would work. It's not that good, but Dependency Injection is quite a complex topic, requiring a lot more complex solutions.